# Difference of dates in Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I am using SQL server. I'm trying to ad a condition that gives me the rows where the difference is date is between 0-3 or if something was opened 0-3 days after the migration date.

When I added the condition to the WHERE clause it acting funcky. I need help figuring out the best way to do this

This give me a result where the date diff is less than 0 even though I say >= 0

```
select * from table_1 
where datediff(day, a.[opened date], d.[UserMigratedDate]) >= 0
```

This give me a result where the date diff is greater than 4 even though I say < 4

```
select * from table_1 
where datediff(day, a.[opened date], d.[UserMigratedDate]) < 4
```

When I use a between it does noting. Am I doing this wrong?

```
select * from table_1 
where (datediff(day, a.[opened date], d.[UserMigratedDate]) >= 0 and datediff(day, a.[opened date], d.[UserMigratedDate]) < 4)
```

Comment: Are you sure you know how datediff works? It does not calculate difference, it calculates how many times the date has **changed** between those dates

Comment: DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate) -  The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.

Comment: Run this query and look at the results `SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'20170621','20170623') `

Comment: @GinaJ That's not true. `Returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.` See the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see your test data that's causing this... because the where clause is constructed correctly. Take the below case for example. ID 2-5 will be returned. Also, your first `datediff()` where you are seeing if the days are >=0 doesn't make sense to be unless someone could migrate something before it was opened...

http://rextester.com/UTLX59878

```
declare @table table (id int, openedDate datetime, UserMigratedDate datetime)
insert into @table
values
(1,'2017-01-01','2016-12-31'), --this technically shouldn't happen
(2,'2017-01-01','2017-01-01'), 
(3,'2017-01-01','2017-01-02'),
(4,'2017-01-01','2017-01-03'),
(5,'2017-01-01','2017-01-04'),
(6,'2017-01-01','2017-01-05')

select
    *,
    datediff(day, openedDate, UserMigratedDate) as theDateDiff
from @table
where 
   datediff(day, openedDate, UserMigratedDate) >= 0 
   and
   datediff(day, openedDate, UserMigratedDate) < 4
```

Comment: Good points, and +1 for the test. The only thing I can think of where this would cause seemingly contrary results would be if there was an issue with dates in a character data type and the date format (`mdy` vs `dmy`) used during conversion was different than expected -- and by chance none of the dates caused an error on conversion. No clue if that is what is going on for OP. http://rextester.com/ESSJMG70459

Comment: That's very interesting @SqlZim. I was super confused at first until i saw where you change the `dateformat` at the top. I was thinking *there is no way that should be interpreted like that by default* You're probably right on this one for the OP. I'd post that as an answer.

Comment: It's a long shot, but the lack of detail in the question isn't very helpful. Also, instead of someone needing to change the `dateformat` I guess I should mention that setting is implicitly set by language. So the same effect happens if the language is set as `'British'`, or some other `dmy` language.